# How can I abort an AJAX request in ajaxStart or ajaxSend?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is ,I have written lots of $.post method in my project.
I want to check the session in every request and depending upon the session value, 
I want to handle my page.But I don`t want to modify all methods($.post) for session,
So I want to check the session in "ajaxStart or ajaxSend" and depending upon 
the response I want to abort the main AJAX call.

I have tried with my little knowledge.The below sample code is not working,because 
$.post is asynchronous.Could any one help me to abort an AJAX Request 
in ajaxStart or ajaxSend state?

```
var pp;
link=function(id){
var url="http://localhost/jqueryui/test.php";
    pp=$.post(url,{"id":id},function(data){
        $("#div"+id).html(data);
    });
}
$(function(){
    $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
        alert("Hi start");
        $(this).show();
               var url="http://localhost/jqueryui/test.php";
           $.post(url,{"id":99},function(data){//checking the session
            if(data == "close")
            pp.abort();         
            });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: @corroded: I am agree,what you have suggested.But I have to made more changes to my code.Because of this reason I am searching some alternative solution.

Comment: i do think that that is more feasible than trying to hack your way with aborting ajax calls. it's a waste of ajax calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop jquery ajax request in ajaxStart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788011/stop-jquery-ajax-request-in-ajaxstart)

Answer (score 5):

You can abort the request by using the second paramter "jqXHR" in the callback:

```
$( document ).ajaxSend( function( event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions )
{
    jqXHR.abort(); // aborts the ajax request
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

See [beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) from the jQuery website.  I don't know what version of jQuery you were using, but the docs say that you can return `false` from `beforeSend` to cancel.