# Stop jquery ajax request in ajaxStart

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to stop the current ajax request from within the jquery global event ajaxStart?

Answer (score 11):

`.ajaxStart` doesn't have access to the xhr object. [`.ajaxSend`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) does, however. You can stop it there. I don't know why you would want to do this, but remember that this is a global ajax event -- so this effectively stops all ajax requests(or at least those that don't have the `global:false` flag).

```
$('some-object').ajaxSend(function(e, xhr) {
    xhr.abort();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI there's a third argument also which is the Ajax Options object used to create the request in case that is of help...

```
                                             |
                                             |
                                            \| /
                                             \/
$('some-object').ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.abort();
});
```