# How to prevent document.ajaxstart on specific selector

Tags: jquery, ajax

My jquery call is as below on textbox.I want to prevent ajaxStart() on this selector

```
$("#ddl_select").keyup(function() { 
    var searchid = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;

    if(searchid!='') {

       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "searchname.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
              $("#result").html(html).show();
          }
       });
    }
});
```

I want to prevent `ajaxStart()` method in above selector.

ajaxStart() code as below

```
jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    //show ajax indicator
    ajaxindicatorstart();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    //hide ajax indicator
    ajaxindicatorstop();
});
```

Only prevent ajaxStart Method but whole function works as it as.

can anybody help me...

Comment: did you try preventDefault?

Comment: Or `jQuery(document).not('#ddl_select').ajaxStart(function ()`?

Comment: @NightOwlPrgmr in function what can i specify ?

Comment: How many different AJAX calls do you have?

Comment: ajaxStart() for loading and ajax on button click event and textbox keyup event.

Comment: this is kinda weird, refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788011/stop-jquery-ajax-request-in-ajaxstart i dont know why you're doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting `ajaxindicatorstart();` and `ajaxindicatorstop();` inside each individual AJAX request except for the selector you didn't want to start it on.

#### Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "searchname.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        // start the indicator right before the AJAX call fires
        ajaxindicatorstart();
    },
    success: function(html)
    {
        // stop the indicator and show the result
        ajaxindicatorstop();
        $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
});
```